# App Inspector for Sencha removed from Chrome store

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, inspector

Any ideas why this extension was marked dangerous and removed from the Chrome store? It happened ~ 10 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and ask the team from digging around on their [github repo](https://github.com/senchalabs/AppInspector/).  It could be that it's not being maintained.  It doesn't look like it's had any updates in like 7 years...